# Large nested dictionary of data only working with "last key"

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, dictionary-comprehension

[EDIT] - Issue not with dictionary itself.  Unmodified copies of original file 'census2010.py' do not display the issue.

I'm trying to encode Excel data into a nested dictionary for further analysis.

I expect to be able to read out any key from the dictionary.  For example, I expect the following to work:

```
>>> census2010.allData['AK']['Anchorage']
{'pop': 291826, 'tracts': 55}
```

What I get is:

```
census2010.allData['AK']['Anchorage']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'AK'
```

The only key that works is:

```
census2010.allData['WY']['Weston']
{'pop': 3894, 'tracts': 1}
```

I've created the Census2010.py file with the data from the censuspopdata.xlsx folder (following process from Chapter 12 of "Automate the Boring Stuff").

Directly looking at Census2010.py shows all the nested keys, but importing 'census2010.py' and interrogating the dictionary only shows the "final" key.

Here's the script to generate census2010.py: (and it runs without error)

```
import openpyxl, pprint, os
print('Opening workbook...')
os.getcwd()
p = os.getcwd()
os.chdir(p + '\\automatestuffdirectorytest\\')
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('censuspopdata.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Population by Census Tract']
countyData = {}
print('Reading rows...')
for row in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
    # Each row in the spreadsheet has data for one census tract.
    state = sheet['B' + str(row)].value
    county = sheet['C' + str(row)].value
    pop = sheet['D' + str(row)].value
    # Make sure the key for this state exists.
    countyData.setdefault(state, {})
    # Make sure the key for this county in this state exists.
    countyData[state].setdefault(county, {'tracts': 0, 'pop': 0})
    # Each row represents one census tract, so increment by one.
    countyData[state][county]['tracts'] += 1
    # Increase the county pop by the pop in this census tract.
    countyData[state][county]['pop'] += int(pop)
print('Writing results...')
resultFile = open('census2010.py', 'w')
resultFile.write('allData = ' + pprint.pformat(countyData))
resultFile.close()
print('Done.')
```

and here's a few snips of the resulting dictionary (3143 lines)

```
allData = {'AK': {'Aleutians East': {'pop': 3141, 'tracts': 1},
        'Aleutians West': {'pop': 5561, 'tracts': 2},
        'Anchorage': {'pop': 291826, 'tracts': 55}, # ...
```

--snip--

```
        'Yukon-Koyukuk': {'pop': 5588, 'tracts': 4}}, # ...
```

--snip--

```
 'WY': {'Albany': {'pop': 36299, 'tracts': 10}, # ...
```

--snip --

```
        'Weston': {'pop': 7208, 'tracts': 2}}}
```

But the only key that seems to be found is [WY][Weston]

```
for i in allData.items():
...    print(i)
...    
('WY', {'Weston': {'pop': 3894, 'tracts': 1}})
```

calling the keys only works with ['WY']['Weston']

```
census2010.allData['WY']['Weston']
{'pop': 3894, 'tracts': 1}
```

Comment: How do you read the result file to convert it in a dictionary?

Comment: Please see how to create a [mre].  Right now it's hard to tell as we don't have (nor need) your raw data, and your dictionary itself might be differently formatted than you expected.  If you can produce a minimal sample where you encounter the same error, it'll be a great starting point.

Comment: Also, considering dumping the resulting `countyData` as a `json` instead of a coercing it as `str`.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  After the post, and reviewing @r.ook response, I tried  simply copying the file and importing the copy works as expected!  Literally copying to 'census2010copy.py' and importing that makes the key calls work.

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. In addition to what someone else said about JSON, you really should use a context manager to handle file objects.

Answer (score 0):

This code might help you:
**Note:** I am not using os module

```
# ! python3
# read_census_excel.txt - Tabultaes population and number of census tracts for
# each county.

import openpyxl, pprint

print('Opening workbook')
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('censuspopdata.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Population by Census Tract')
county_data = {}

print('Reading rows...')
for row in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
    # Each row in the spreadsheet has data for one census tract.
    state = sheet['B' + str(row)].value
    county = sheet['C' + str(row)].value
    pop = sheet['D' + str(row)].value

    # Make sure the key for this state exists.
    county_data.setdefault(state, {})
    # Make sure the key for this county in this state exists.
    county_data[state].setdefault(county, {'tracts': 0, 'pop': 0})

    # Each row represents one census tract, so increment by one.
    county_data[state][county]['tracts'] += 1
    # Increase the county pop by the pop in this census tract.
    county_data[state][county]['pop'] += int(pop)

# Open a new text file and write the contents of county_data to it.
print('Writing results...')
result_file = open('census2010.py', 'w')
result_file.write('all_data= ' + pprint.pformat(county_data))
result_file.close()
print('Done')
```